# Can ScriptProcessor's onaudioprocess event speed be effected by setInterval or requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, setinterval, web-audio-api, requestanimationframe, scriptprocessor

i am using Web Audio API's `ScriptProcessor` and it's `onaudioprocess` event for repetitive callbacks such as a metronome.

I tried using `requestAnimationFrame` and `analyser` node for audio visualisation in the same app.

It seems like the speed of which `onaudioprocess` event happens is being slowed down by half when trying to draw to a `canvas` using `requestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval` .

The question is, is it normal that other stuff can interrupt `onaudioprocess` speed? or am i doing something hugely wrong?

Or it is being effected by `canvas` drawing stuff? Because i tried using RAF and set Interval to log stuff to console and it did not effect anything.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's kind of difficult to tell exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptProcessor really shouldn't be used as an event source like that.  If you just want to build a metronome, I'd refer you to the HTML5Rocks article I wrote early this year - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.

Comment: Thanks chris, i have read your article it is great. I was trying to see if there are other ways for repetitive callbacks. It seems like libraries such as [WAAClock](https://github.com/sebpiq/WAAClock) are using ScriptProcessor too.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKBRc/1/) this is how i made a metro object for repetitive callback.

Comment: So `ScriptProcessor`'s speed can be effected by other stuff in the execution thread?